# how to autosize textbox in GridView row in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to add a databound text box in a GridView row:

```
<ItemTemplate >
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox" runat="server" Visible="true" Enabled="true" 
                 Wrap="true" text='<%#Eval("Notes")%>' TextMode="MultiLine" >
    </asp:TextBox>                  
</ItemTemplate>
```

I can't figure out how to make the textbox autosize to the height of the GridView row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know the height of a content in a multiline textbox you can you a simple formula depend on the font size of the textbox.
`enter code here`Example (the number are not real).
If a line of 80 characters consume 400px in width and 20px in height, a line of 160 characters consume always 400px in width but 40px in height.
So, in the Height attribute of the TextBox you can write

Height='<% (Eval("Comments").Length / 80) * 20 %>'

```
 <asp:TextBox TextMode="multiLine" Width="400" Text='<%#Eval("field_name") %>' 
   Height='<%# Eval("field_name").ToString().Length*2%>' `enter code here`
    ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score -1):

You Can do by java script too

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Automatic Resize TextBox</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setHeight(txtdesc) {
txtdesc.style.height = txtdesc.scrollHeight + "px";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDesc" runat= "server" TextMode="MultiLine"  onkeyup="setHeight(this);" onkeydown="setHeight(this);" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```